# Convert Column in CSV to list and sum the total of each return

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I am trying to sum the total of returns for each name in a column taken from a CSV file.

For example, the returns are a,b,c,d,a,c,d,c,b.. and so on in no particular order.

I would like to:

1. Print the returns into a separate file (ie getting a,b,c and d)
2. Total the amount of times EACH return was found in the column.

I want my printed return in a separate file to look something like this:

```
a: 345
b. 230
c: 450
d: 234
```

Comment: Could you provide a few lines of the file?  I'm having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: import os
import csv

#Locate CSV File
csvpath = os.path.join('..', 'pypoll', 'election_data.csv')
newfile = os.path.join('..', 'pypoll','election_final.txt')

#Track parameters
votes = []
candidates = []
total_votes = 0

Comment: #Extract first row
        total_votes = total_votes + 1
        candidates = first_row[2]
        print(candidates)
#For loop to gather parameters
        for row in csv_reader:
        # count the total votes
                total_votes = sum(row[first_row[2]]))
                print(total_votes)
        #Gather candidates names

Comment: Edit the question to add more information.  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: It's not quite clear as to what you're looking for, can you please add the `csv` top 5 entries in a tabular view and mention what the output should look like (examples of point 1 and point 2)

Answer (score 0):

try pd.to_json() function.

Here is the example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=20
columns_name = list('abcd')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(5,4)),
              columns= columns_name)
print(df)
df.sum().to_json("result.json")
```

The output to console will be  :

```
a   b   c   d
0  56  91  65  82
1  63  65  50  78
2  46  43  75   3
3  37  96  84  13
4  40  59  61  66
```

the file will be

```
{"a":165,"b":230,"c":234,"d":336}
```

hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see image. I would like to count how many times each name appears in "candidates" to see how many times each candidate received a vote.